# How to restart the game when draw happens

Tags: c, random, numbers, repeat

I want to write a program to play `Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard` 
So far everything works, but if it gets to a draw, I don't really know how to restart the game. I tried it this way: If both first and second players are showing the same thing, it will just repeat it over and over again without re-shuffling. How do I restart the game?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
enum variablen {scissor=1, paper, rock, lizard, spock} ;
int i;

const char * vergleich(int random) {
    switch(random) {
        case scissor: return "Siccor";
        case paper: return "Paper";
        case rock: return "Rock";
        case lizard: return "Lizard";
        case spock: return "Spock";
        default: break;
    }
    return "";
}

int new_game() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s1 = rand() % 5+1;
    int s2 = rand() % 5+1;
    printf("player1 shows %s", vergleich(s1));
    printf("\n\tif Player 2 plays %s or %s Player1 wins\n", vergleich(s1+1), vergleich(s1+3));
    printf("player2 shows: %s\n", vergleich(s2));
    if(s2 == s1 + 1 || s2 == s1 +3 || s1 == s2) {
        if(s1==s2) {
                printf("draw \n");
                i = 0;
        }else{printf("player1 wins"); i = 4;}
    }else{printf("player2 wins"); i = 4;}
    return 0;
}



int main() {
    printf("Welcome\n");
    while(i == 0) {new_game();}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it counter-indicated to seed the RNG more than once (per thread)?

Comment: @apokryfos i dont really understand what you mean, but is there a way to get it shuffled everytime i call that new_game function?

Comment: Call `srand()` once at the entry to `main()`. Don't call it every time you call `new_game()`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thank you that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

`srand(time(NULL));` initializes the random number generator with the current system time. Note that "time" is system time in seconds. If you call `time(NULL)` very quickly in a row, it will always return the same value as we are still within the same second. Note that computers today are lightning fast. However, when you initialize the random number generator with the same value, it will also produce the same sequence of random values (again and again), that's because the random number generator of C doesn't produce random numbers at all, it just produces pseudo-random numbers and the sequence of numbers is entirely defined by the value you use to initialize the generator.

Solution: Don't re-initialize the random number generator at all. Initialize it once, so that the sequence is a different one each time the program runs, but then keep just using it without re-initialization. Or in much simpler words:

Move `srand(time(NULL));` to the beginning of the `main` function.